# Can I cut up sheets of cement board and use it as wall shingles?

Tags: exterior, cement-board, sheathing

I have seen lots of great fiber cement board shingled projects popping up around my neighborhood lately, and would like to do the same for my garage. Currently it is done in vinyl which I absolutely hate.

As an avid DIYer and recent home buyer, I'd like to do it on a budget. I found [Durock Next Gen Cement Board](https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.12-durock-next-gen-cement-board-panel-32-x-5.1000113392.html) at HD (Canada) at around $33 a sheet.

At that price I could do my entire garage for $700!!

My question is this:  living in Montreal, with harsh freeze/thaw cycles, will this product pose any problems? 
 I would like to do 12"x96" shingles that are blind screwed with SS screws. I do not want to paint or finish In any way.

Thoughts?

Comment: 96" planks wouldn't normally be called "shingles". That's simply lap siding. At any rate, how does one get a 96" board out of a 5' panel?

Answer (score 2):

Cement board and fibercement siding (such as that from [GAF](http://www.gaf.com/other_building_products/siding/weatherside_fiber_cement_siding) or [Hardie](https://www.jameshardie.com/Products/HardieShingle-Siding)) are very different things. I'd never have considered cement board as an exterior product, especially in a climate with severe freeze/thaw cycles. I'd expect it to simply disintegrate as it'll absorb moisture readily.

Also, to cut that into siding shingles would be a monumental task, generating huge amounts of carcinogenic dust and burning through a good heap of blades.

Comment: Thanks Isherwood, I copied the wrong link, the product comes in two sheet sizes. Cutting it isn't much of an issue. I worked in a shop that made decorative objects out of bent laminations of a fiber cement board and it rips like a dream. Maybe not the best dream youve ever had...

Comment: http://www.schleehdesign.com/cnt/popup.php?lng=e&section=vessels&id=179

Comment: But given the price, even if it lasted half as long as the more expensive pre fab shingles, it would be worth it.  As you mentioned, my one concern would be how it would weather. I guess the smartest thing would be to leave a piece outside for a winter.

Comment: Fibercement siding often has a 50 year warranty. Chances are you won't get anywhere near even half that with a product that's not intended for the purpose (you're mounting it from one edge!). Also, since degradation of any material tends to be parabolic in severity, one year in the weather probably won't tell you anything useful. The bottom line is that it's a risk of $700 plus your labor.